# How to tell Jackson to serialize objects through fields and ignore properties?

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, jackson

I would like objects serialized into JSON and XML through JAXB annotations in Spring Boot with Jackson.

Take a look at these:

```
public interface Permission {

    boolean isAllowed();

    boolean isExpired();

}

@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserPermissionDto implements Permission {

    @XmlElement
    protected boolean enabled;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public boolean setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isAllowed() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return enabled;
    }

}
```

I would like to see `UserPermissionDto` serialized without `allowed` and `expired` properties.

I already tried customizing `ObjectMapper` through `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, with an `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` added, and `autoDetectGettersSetters` set to `false`, but the same issue persisted.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
    jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
            .annotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance()))
            .autoDetectGettersSetters(false)
            .build();
}
```

I can't figure out why `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` didn't work out. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) to ignore the properties during serialization and de-serialization.

Use [@XmlTransient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) to ignore the properties during XML marshalling/unmarshalling.

Comment: I would like to stick with JAXB annotations.

Comment: Is there a way for it to be automatically inferred since I am already specifying `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`?

Comment: `@XmlAccessorType` specifies whether fields or properties are serialized. It does not mean ignore. `XmlAccessType.FIELD` means only fields are serialized and `XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` means serialize/deserialize only properties getter/setter. Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) for detailed info.

Comment: Yes but in my class, only `enabled` field is present. So I suppose that only `enabled` field should be serialized, not including the `allowed` and `expired` properties.

Comment: ok I see the code now. try `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` which will only serialize annotated fields .